# Change ORDS URL with IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: oracle, url-rewriting, iis-10, oracle-ords

I've written a set of REST APIs (Oracle ORDS) with the URL following format:
https://servername:8443/ords/schema_alias/module_name/handler_name/p1/p2

The requirement from the client is that it be in the following format (will be used by an external tool):
https://servername:8443/handler_name/p1/p2

We are using IIS and I tried to achieve this with URL Rewrite:

**Pattern**: ^handler_name/([_0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)

**Action type**: Rewrite

**Rewrite URL**: ords/schema_alias/module_name/handler_name/{R:1}/{R:2}

The Test Pattern option in URL Rewrite worked as expected.

However when I test the URL I get a page not found (404). I am able to verify the configuration in the C:\inetpub\wwwwroot\site_name\Web.config file.

Can anyone please shed some light as to why the web server does not recognise the URL?

EDIT: additional information after @Deepak-MSFT 's Answer

Below is my rule's configuration:
[image]

And the detailed error message:
[image]

I have added the folder, but that did not make a difference:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\b******MS

Below are the IIS sites:
[image]

Comment: You can help yourself with FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Thank you @Lex Li
I've tried FRT as per your suggestion, but the FailedReqLogFiles folder remains emprty for my request. Seems IIS does not recognise the URL that 'n specified in URL Rewrite.

Comment: 1) Make sure you use a privacy tab of your browser. 2) Make sure FRT is enabled on the site, not merely adding an FRT rule.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested below URL Rewrite rule is rewriting the URL from `http://localhost:8443/handler_name/p1/p2` to `http://localhost:8443/ords/schema_alias/module_name/handler_name/p1/p2`

```
 <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rule-1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost:8443" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/handler_name(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="ords/schema_alias/module_name/handler_name{C:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

**Test Result**

[image]

If you still get the 404 error then make sure the path in the file system is correct and folder exists.

Further, you could share the screenshot of the detailed 404 error. It could show the **module name** that is having issue. It could help you narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak-MSFT

I'll edit my post with more information.

Comment: @JacquesB, I have checked the edited information and noticed that for Failed Request Tracing you have specified the status code range from `200-399`. `404` is outside the range you specified. this is the reason logs are not getting generated. You could modify the range to include 404 errors.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the mistake @Deepak-MSFT . I have corrected it:
<tracing>
            <traceFailedRequests>
                <add path="*">
                    <traceAreas>
                        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Rewrite" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    </traceAreas>
                    <failureDefinitions timeTaken="00:00:00" statusCodes="200-404" />
                </add>
            </traceFailedRequests>
        </tracing>

This folder is still empty (I have tried few requests):
C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles

Comment: I would suggest you check [this image](https://imgur.com/a/S8GF4D1) and see whether you enable the FRT like this? For testing purposes, disable all the Rewrite rules and try to browse the path in the browser. Are you able to see the desired page?

Comment: Thank you, @Deepak-MSFT - I get the logs now.
I see may rows with HANDLER_PRECONDITION_NOT_MATCH, however, I also get URL_REWRITE_START, RULE_EVALUATION_START, PATTERN_MATCH, REWRITE_ACTION, RULE_EVALUATION_END,  URL_CHANGED, URL_REWRITE_END. I also see the desired URL in these logs. I do not know how to figure our what went wrong though.

Comment: @JacquesB , in the FRT logs, do you see any row with the text like `IIS Web Core`? or do you see any part where it shows some issue? You could take the screenshot of that part and share here. We could help you check and verify it.